# Best practice for breaking up long lines in JS

Tags: javascript, code-formatting

I've read several posts on this topic here, but I'm still uncertain how I should handle this issue.

In truth, the lines are in the source code much longer
e.g.

```
console.log("html : "+"<li><a href=\""+el.find("link").text()+"\">"+el.find("title").text()+"</a>");
```

breaking it up in

```
console.log("html : "
  +"<li><a href=\""
  +el.find("link").text()
  +"\">"
  +el.find("title").text()
  +"</a>");
```

everything still works fine, but JSLint tells me "*Bad line breaking before '+'*"

What is the best practice, recommend way to keep the source human readable (production code will be minified).

Comment: JSLint uses the the [convention rules](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) written by mr. Crockford. In the chapter about "Line Length" he says: "`Place the break after an operator, ideally after a comma.`"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must end line with +

Otherwise interpreters might treat it as the end of a line. ( thanks to Scimonster for explanation )

```
console.log('html: ' +
    '<li><a href="' +
    el.find('link').text() +
    '">' +
    el.find('title').text() +
    '</a>');
```

I recommend you to use single quotes in your JavaScript and double quotes in HTML. Then there is no need to escape double quotes, it also improves readability of your code.

Comment: I like the part about single vs double quotes in JavaScript/HTML. Will pay more attention about that from now on! ;)

Comment: It's not true that 'he must to...'. There are other options (and better in some cases) as you can see here.

Answer (score 7):

Not related to the line breaking, but an alternative to concatenating strings is to use [substitution strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log), which sometimes makes things more manageable.

```
console.log('html: <li><a href="%s">%s</a>',
    el.find('link').text(),
    el.find('title').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do in such cases

```
var str = "html : "+"<li><a href=\"LINK\">TEXT</a>";
var str = str.replace('LINK',el.find("link").text()).replace('TEXT',el.find("title").text());
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Of course it works, but i don't think it make it more understandable.